# Uncaught TypeError: window.HybridApp.setMessage is not a function error

Tags: javascript, android, webview, proguard

I want to make an app for hybridApp but some errors occurred.
 "Uncaught TypeError: window.HybridApp.setMessage is not a function error"
 I tried to find the cause, but I could not.

**proguard**

```
-keepattributes JavascriptInterface
-keep public class com.test.crosswalkdemo2$AndroidBridge
-keep public class * implements com.test.crosswalkdemo2$AndroidBridge
-keepclassmembers class com.test.crosswalkdemo2$AndroidBridge {
<methods>;
}
-keepclassmembers class * {
 @android.webkit.JavascriptInterface <methods>;
}
```

**main**

```
public class AndroidBridge {

    @JavascriptInterface
    public void setMessage(final String text) { // must be final
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                mTextView.setText(text);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**html**

```
<script language="JavaScript">
function setMessage(arg) { 
document.getElementById('textMessageFromApp').innerHTML = arg;
}

function sendMessage(msg){
window.HybridApp.setMessage(msg);
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<h2>Hybrid App (WEB+APP)</h2>
<hr/>
<input type="text" id="textMessageFromWeb" value="Hello, Hybrid(WEB)!!"/>
<input type="button" value="Send"        onclick="sendMessage(document.getElementById('textMessageFromWeb').value)"/>
```

please see my code and help.